# Git rebase conflict understanding

Tags: git, version-control

In my workflow, I have two main branches, `master` and `development`.

We decided recently to rebase `development` on `master` because we made a lot of fixes on `master` and we continued the development of the features on `development`.

Our goal is at the end to remove totally `development` and keep one branch to change our workflow because it is not perfect for our usage...

So we had some conflict (normal after 7 months of development on differents branches), but some were quit weird...

For example, a lot of time we had something like :

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add/rm ..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#       added by them:      X
#       added by us:        Y
```

But for the `added by us`, the file were present in `master` and in `development` for commit. You have to know that the files in question were at least *10 months* old....

My question here is : *What is the exact meaning of `added by us` ?*

And *Is `rebase` a good practice ?*

Comment: When you want to collapse commits in your personal repository that you have never shared, ever; rebase is a good idea.   If you want to collapse commits that have been used by other members of your team and want to earn their hatred, rebase is good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that the `us` means your current branch, and `them` the commit you are currently rebasing. But that’s actually a very minor point, because:

**You should not be rebasing 7 months worth of work!!!**

Rebasing should almost only be used on local code, that is not pushed yet. If you using it for something else, you are probably doing something wrong. This is one of those times.

The *default* answer is merging, rebasing is the special case. And so you should also merge in this case. Consequences of rebasing:

- You have to do 100 merges instead of 1 and care for conflicts 100 times instead of once (every step in rebase is a merge)
- Your history is a [total lie](http://paul.stadig.name/2010/12/thou-shalt-not-lie-git-rebase-ammend.html). I do assume that you don’t thoroughly test every rebased commit (because that obviously would be crazy).  The result of that is, that at a later point none of the code in there might actually work or even make sense. Information about conflict resolution is also lost (it is not lost if you do a merge – you can get it by diffing against both parents).

Comment: Rebasing is a valid tool, even for large chunks of history, in the case of major branch rewriting.

Comment: I also think is completely valid, you could "squash" those commits before the rebase to make things easier. So it is something like "rebase -i commitBeforeBranchCreation", do all the squash, fix necessary and then "rebase masterBranch" ... in that way the conflicts are a lot less.